# Anova in R with repetitions

Tags: r, statistics, anova

Ok, So I am taking an statistics course (I'm a PhD Student) and I am having some trouble performing an anova analysis in R. The code is like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x1 = c(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1),
  x2 = c(-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1),
  x3 = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  y = c(59, 74, 50, 69, 50, 81, 46, 79, 61, 70, 58, 67, 54, 85, 44, 81)
)
```

I know I can just perform an anova with

```
summary(aov(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = df))
```

The problem is that the residual analysis is wrong. It gives me an SQR of 474 and 12 degrees of freedom, but it should be 64 and 8 respectively. I'm sure of this because not only we did it in class with my professor by hand (that took a while) but we also did this in Matlab through more than one method and got the same results. Any idea why is R giving me an wrong answer? I tried using another method, like anova.lme but didn't get it to work. Just looking at the degrees of freedom, if I have 16 experiments and I calculate 8 means, that gives me 8 dfs. Other way to look at it, I have 16 experiments and 8 different groups (one for each normalization interaction) which also gives me 8 dfs. The formula for degrees of freedom for the SQR is N - k, k being the different groups. In this case, the groups are all possible interactions, so 16 experiments - 8 possible interactions = 8 degrees of freedom.This already proves that 12 dfs is wrong (I have no idea from where this 12 is coming). Below is the answer I get from R, the SQG from x1,x2,x3 are all correct, as are their degrees of freedom. But since the residuals is wrong, my F values are all also off.

The interactions (groups) I'm talking about are:

```
x1 x2 x3
-1 -1 -1;
 1 -1 -1;
-1  1 -1;
 1  1 -1;
-1 -1  1;
 1 -1  1;
-1  1  1;
 1  1  1;
```

And below is the answer I get from R

```
        Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
x1           1   2116  2116.0  53.570 9.23e-06 ***
x2           1    100   100.0   2.532    0.138    
x3           1      9     9.0   0.228    0.642    
Residuals   12    474    39.5
```

Thanks for the help and sorry for any mistakes, English is not my main language.

Comment: Why does `x1` only have 14 values while the other vectors have 16? When you say what the answer "should be", what definition are you using exactly? Do you have a reference?

Comment: I don't understand how you would get to 8 degrees of freedom with those factors

Comment: My bad, I must have not copied all values, x1 has 16 values also, I'll edit. By definition I mean that I have calculated by hand and on Matlab and I am positive the degrees os freedom should be 8, not 12. And as for the degrees of freedom, I explained how in my question and edit it with more information, is there something you don't agree with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are modeling `x1`, `x2` and `x3` as separate covariates but you seem to want to combine that into a single factor. You can use the `interaction()` function in R to do that. For example

```
summary(aov(y ~ interaction(x1, x2, x3), data = df))
#                         Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
# interaction(x1, x2, x3)  7   2635   376.4   47.05 7.07e-06 ***
# Residuals                8     64     8.0                     
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Which seems to give the values you were expecting Basically it creates as new variable for you with 8 different values

```
with(df, table(interaction(x1, x2, x3)))
# -1.-1.-1  1.-1.-1  -1.1.-1   1.1.-1  -1.-1.1   1.-1.1   -1.1.1    1.1.1 
#        2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I put everything on my call to R `summary(aov(y ~ x1 +x2 +x3 + interaction(x1, x2, x3), data = df))` and I got what I wanted, just need to ignore the interaction line on the summary, but all values for dfs, F and significance are now correct.